# drupal_get_form in a condition won't trigger the form submit

Tags: 7, forms

I'm trying to understand why when I call a form through drupal_get_form the submit part of it reload the page and if I don't call the form with drupal_get_form on that page again, it won't trigger the submits :(

```
function myFunction()
{
    if (isset($_POST['token'])) {
        return drupal_get_form('my_form');
    }

//why do I need to do that in order to get the submit form working?
    elseif($_POST['form_id']){
        return drupal_get_form('my_form');
    }
//why do I need to do that in order to get the submit form working?

    else drupal_goto('wherever');
}
```

In that case the first condition display my form but if I don't use that code below it won't trigger the submit form.

```
    elseif($_POST['form_id']){
        return drupal_get_form('my_form');
    }
```

The form is working fine, same goes for the submit, it's somehow related to that condition. I've got the feeling that because the submit is a button it will reload in order to get the form_submit but will fail to retrieve it as the condition is not working anymore.
Does the drupal_retrieve_form would be more appropriate?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Just to get my form submit working without having to reuse return drupal_get_form('my_form');

Comment: Could you post your `hook_form()` and `hook_form_submit()`?

Comment: It's not related to the form_submit as it's not even triggered and the form is just 2 submits, they will reload the page but do nothing else unless I use the drupal_get_form and then will trigger the correct submit_form. see above

Comment: If you don't invoke `drupal_get_form` in the callback for the page submission, then the form won't be retrieved from cache, and no handlers will be executed @Namari. Read through the code for [`drupal_build_form()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21form.inc/function/drupal_build_form/7) and it will all be clear. Yes, `drupal_retrieve_form` is an option if you're happy buildling it manually